# How to capure my web browser's and any other programs' http requests on my own laptop using mitmproxy?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, proxy

I am using mitmproxy on ubuntu 18.04

I know how to capture another devices' traffic on my wifi network. but I don't know how to capture http requests which are sent by programs in my own laptop (where mitm has been installed)

my laptops ip is 192.168.xx.10

routers ip is 192.168.xx.1

When I tried to do this using arpspoof, someone said that arpspoof isn't used for capture own traffic and to follow the instructions except arpspoofing which have been given in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdj_BiPt6Bw

so now I don't use arpspoofing

I tried following

using port 4001 (didn't use 8080 bc it is already in use)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp2  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4001
```

and then

```
mitmproxy --listen-port 4001
```

and it shows nothing

so what should I do for this?

Comment: Can you just set the program to use your proxy? Also the firewall rule doesn't make sense; prerouting isn't used for locally generated traffic, nor should you specify an input interface. But you shouldn't need firewall rules at all if you just change proxy settings.